# Visual Studion 2017 Preview 5.0

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I installed to the latest VS 2017 Preview version this morning and now I am unable to build asp.net core projects on docker. I've tried a couple that were OK this morning but both fail with this error:

> Error      (Line: 11, Col: 7, Idx: 246) - (Line: 11, Col: 7, Idx: 246): Expected 'MappingStart', got 'SequenceStart' (at Line: 11, Col: 7, Idx: 246).  docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets  294

Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: It *is* a preview, after all. File an issue.

Comment: I have @ChrisPratt but that does not mean that I don't want to find out if anyone has gotten this issue sorted. It seems to be a matter of how to format the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in this version of VS the docker compose file syntax is more restricted. I had a mixed bag of syntax types in my environment section but had to redo them all in this format:

```
environment:
    key1: "value1"
    key2: "value2"
```

**UPDATE**
Since this is getting a few hits, I want to add this. If you have a Settings class that contains a List of sub settings classes, this seems to be the correct syntax ....

```
environment:
  Class:Property: "SomeValue"
  Class:ListOfSubClass__SubClasc01__Property01: "Value"
  Class:ListOfSubClass__SubClasc01__Property02: "Value"
  Class:ListOfSubClass__SubClasc02__Property01: "Value"
  Class:ListOfSubClass__SubClasc02__Property02: "Value"
```

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows containers? I thought colons didn't work at all in Linux containers for environment variable names? do you only get one colon for windows?

Comment: Linux containers. This also works @JustinDearing :
Class:Property: "value"